# Angular 6 HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am currently developing an Angular 6 application running on a Node.js server. When I try calling http get `http:localhost:3000/gallery`, I get a client-side httpErrorResponse telling me:

**Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/gallery**
[image]

This is my client side code in gallery.service.ts

```
import { GalleryItem } from "./gallery-item.model";
import { HttpClient } from "../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "../../../node_modules/@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "../../../node_modules/rxjs";
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

const BACKEND_URL = environment.apiURL + "/gallery";

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class GalleryService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    private selectedItem: GalleryItem;
    private selectedItemUpdated = new Subject<GalleryItem>();
    private galleryItems: GalleryItem[] = [];
    private galleryItemsUpdated = new Subject<GalleryItem[]>();

    getGalleryItems() {
        console.log(1);
        this.http.get<{galleryItems: GalleryItem[]}>("http://localhost:3000/gallery").subscribe((getData) => {
            this.galleryItems = getData.galleryItems;
            this.galleryItemsUpdated.next([...this.galleryItems]);
        });
        console.log(2);
    }

    getGalleryItemsListener() {
        return this.galleryItemsUpdated.asObservable();
    }

    getItem(id) {
        this.http.get<{galleryItems:GalleryItem}>(BACKEND_URL + '/' + id).subscribe((getData) => {
            console.log(getData);
            this.selectedItem = getData.galleryItems;
            this.selectedItemUpdated.next(this.selectedItem);
        });
    }

    getItemUpdated() {
        return this.selectedItemUpdated.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Specifically, it is the `getGalleryItems()` that is not working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your API is returning XML / HTML. Are you expecting JSON? If you check the network tab of the developer tools you should be able to see what's sent, and figure out why

Comment: What you are getting is not a valid JSON

Comment: Yes, you should review your server side because you are not getting a JSON object in the client side